# Fogbugz XML API - Get list of cases for specific milestone

Tags: fogbugz-api

I can query a list of cases for a milestone with

```
https://example.fogbugz.com/api.asp?token=xxx&cmd=search&q=fixfor:v0.3.02&cols=sFixFor,ixFixFor
```

the `fixfor` parameter takes the name of the milestone.  Is there any way of specifying the milestone by `ixFixFor`

Answer (score 0):

First way:
You can create special filter in FogBugz and then set this filter as default using the API

`cmd=setCurrentFilter&sFilter=402`

and than get list of cases for specific milestone.

Second way:
Get all cases and than filter them by milestone using column &cols=sFixFor,ixFixFor